# Is my HTML logic correct about positions/pixels/divs/etc.?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make sure I understand it fully. Suppose I want a page that is exactly 600 pixels wide and 1000 pixels tall, separated into 3 equally-spaced columns by divs with borders of 1 pixels each. Then the divs should each be 998 pixels high and 198 pixels wide, and they should be positioned **absolutely** with respective (top, left) positions of (0,0), (0,200) and (0,400), because a 600-pixels-wide body corresponds to absolute horizontal pixel positions of 0 through 599. These 3 divs will take up the entire width of the body. I don't have to worry about margins of the divs or padding of the body because those values are **irrelevant** when absolute positioning is active. Correct?

Here's my code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>div practice</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            height: 1000px;
            width: 600px;   
        }
        .outercol
        {
            position: absolute;
            width: 198px;
            height: 998px;
            border: solid 1px black;
        }
        #co1
        {
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
        }
        #co2
        {   
            top: 0px;
            left: 200px;
        }
        #co3
        {
            top: 0px;
            left: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
     <div class="outercol" id="co1">
        <p>This text is inside column 1</p>
     </div>
     <div class="outercol" id="co2">
        <p>This text is inside column 2</p>  
     </div>
     <div class="outercol" id="co3">
        <p>This text is inside column 3</p>  
     </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you test it?  What doesn't work about it?

Comment: Padding moves your borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens when you add padding to the div's now. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fYa4f/)

Instead try something like what i have below. It uses percentages which makes it a little bit more difficult but it will work out better in the long run.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="block">
        Block 1
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        Block 2
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        Block 3
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}
.block {
    float: left;
    width: 31%;
    padding: 1%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/U7m5g/)

To increase the padding, you take the width down by 1% and you have an extra .5% to add to the padding.

Example:

```
width: 31%;
padding: 1%;
```

becomes

```
width: 30%;
padding: 1.5%;
```

and the same goes for the other way.

Hope this all makes sense